# Render a model like include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wondering how can i render in my header file a search model. Pretty much like an include in php, but with rails i want to render the new form into my header. I base my style of search on this video http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised but not to sure on how to render the code in to my header. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can't watch video without subscribing. Could you desrcibe in more detail what exactly your problem is? You could create a partial with the html for the searchbox and just use the render :partial => "search_box" wherever you want to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a partial?

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

You can do something like this:

```
<%= render "shared/search", :locals => { :search_string => @search_string } %>
```

Which will render what is in the `app/views/shared/_search.html.erb` file.